# focus on a textfield the background is not changing colour

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi this may be a silly question but when i click on a textfield i want the back ground to change colour but i do not see why it is not working

could someone tell me where i am going wrong

code is below

```
//JQUERY
$(function() {

    $('input[type="text"]').focus(function() 
    {
        $(this).addClass("focus");
    });

    $('input[type="text"]').blur(function() 
    {
        $(this).removeClass("focus");
    });

})
```

;

```
//CSS
.focus {
    border: 2px solid #AA88FF;
    background-color: #FFEEAA;
}
```

HTML
//All the textfield are `type text` when i inspect them too

Comment: Looks good to me too: http://jsfiddle.net/sANH7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in CSS with no need for jQuery (for the newer major browsers at least)

```
input[type="text"]:focus
{
   border: 2px solid #AA88FF;
   background-color: #FFEEAA;
}
```

:)

Comment: He got the best way to do it. Doing this with jQuery is unnecessary.

Comment: Absolutely! jQuery is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using jQuery here, its perfectly possible to change background colours with CSS.

```
    input[type=text]:focus {
        border: 2px solid #AA88FF;
        background-color: #FFEEAA;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a quirk of the jquery library. Try:

```
$(this).css({...})
```

instead of:

```
$(this).addClass(...)
```

and it should work.